# Python NOR Returning Odd Values

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, nor

I am trying to get a NOR of 2 values

```
a = 0b1010
b = 0b0101

print(~ (a | b))
```

The current output is `-16`, but if I do this by hand

```
   1010
OR 0101
--------
   1111

NOT 1111
--------
    0000
```

So, this should give a value of `0`, not `-16`. Why does it do this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These operations are being done with 32-bit integers (or 64-bit integers in a 64-bit version of Python).

```
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010
 OR 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101
 ------------------------------------------
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111

NOT 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111
-------------------------------------------
    1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000
```

Which, taken as a signed integer, is the two's complement representation of -16, because you have to add 16 to reach zero (and a carry).

To fix it, explicitly xor with `0b1111` instead of using `~`.

```
print((a | b) ^ 0b1111)
```

Comment: Python integers aren't really either 32 or 64-bit. They expand to whatever size is needed to fit them (in units of 31 bits, I think). That doesn't change your main point, but you could easily put a `...` at the start of the leading `0`s or `1`s and be a bit more correct, since conceptually, they go on forever.

Comment: They start out as some size though, and I'm pretty sure it's the machine's word size.